# On the usual argument for a derivative not being defined at an endpoint

Tags: calculus

In elementary calculus, a usual argument for the derivative not being defined at an endpoint is that one of the lateral derivatives not being defined. See for example [this](https://math.dartmouth.edu/opencalc2/cole/lecture21.pdf) page 3. Central to the definition of the derivative is that of a limit.

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow a}f(x)=b \Leftrightarrow \forall_{\epsilon}\exists_{\delta}\forall_{x}(x\in D \ \land \ x\in N_{\delta}(a)\ \Rightarrow \ f(x) \in N_{\epsilon}(b) )$$

I fail to see why they say that for an endpoint the derivative is not defined, when clearly using this definition of limit we can speak of continuity at an endpoint... For the left endpoint of a closed interval, the left limit would be defined for any $b$, since the premiss of the implication is false, making the whole implication true for whatever b.

Comment: Could you give some cites for your claim that "the derivative not being defined at an endpoint" is indeed the usual argument? The textbook I teach from, *Calculus: Graphical, Numerical, Algebraic*, does not say this, but explicitly states that at an endpoint of the natural domain we use the one-sided derivative.

Comment: @RoryDaulton I gave one link in the post. I've read others in other languages than English...